# Xcode - Warning: Implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99

Tags: c, xcode

Getting a warning : Implicit declaration of function 'Fibonacci' is invalid in C99.
What's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int input;
    printf("Please give me a number : ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    getchar();
    printf("The fibonacci number of %d is : %d", input, Fibonacci(input)); //!!!

}/* main */

int Fibonacci(int number)
{
    if(number<=1){
        return number;
    }else{
        int F = 0;
        int VV = 0;
        int V = 1;
        for (int I=2; I<=getal; I++) {
            F = VV+V;
            VV = V;
            V = F;
        }
        return F;
    }
}/*Fibonacci*/
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The function has to be declared before it's getting called. This could be done in various ways:

- Write down the prototype in a header
  Use this if the function shall be callable from several source files. Just write your prototype
  `int Fibonacci(int number);`
  down in a `.h` file (e.g. `myfunctions.h`) and then `#include "myfunctions.h"` in the C code.
- Move the function before it's getting called the first time
  This means, write down the function
  `int Fibonacci(int number){..}`
  before your `main()` function
- Explicitly declare the function before it's getting called the first time
  This is the combination of the above flavors: type the prototype of the function in the C file before your `main()` function

As an additional note: if the function `int Fibonacci(int number)` shall only be used in the file where it's implemented, it shall be declared `static`, so that it's only visible in that translation unit.

Comment: why do i have to type `int Fibonacci(int number);` in header? i think `int Fibonacci(int);` should be fine?

Answer (score 31):

The compiler wants to know the function before it can use it

just declare the function before you call it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Fibonacci(int number); //now the compiler knows, what the signature looks like. this is all it needs for now

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int input;
    printf("Please give me a number : ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    getchar();
    printf("The fibonacci number of %d is : %d", input, Fibonacci(input)); //!!!

}/* main */

int Fibonacci(int number)
{
//…
```

Answer (score 4):

in c
The function has to be declared before it's getting called

include head file

Answer (score 1):

I have the same warning (it's make my app cannot build). When I add `C function` in `Objective-C's .m file`, But forgot to declared it at `.h` file.