# How to replace NSLog with DLog with common file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios11

My current project does not contain prefix.pch file.I added the following code on **Constants.h** file

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

Then I replaced my NSLog in my viewcontroller like the following:

```
DLog(@“Replaced”)
```

But I always got the error like **Implicit declaration of function 'DLog' is invalid in C99** on my this specific view controller .

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: for me works just fine

Comment: @ReinierMelian, not get you..

Comment: I had added a constants.h file in a example project with your code and works just fine @IKKA

Comment: Did you read [implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110645/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-is-invalid-in-c99)

Comment: How to get scope of my Constants.h file without import in prefix.pch file.?