# Implicit declaration of function when using macros

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add custom logging to my objc application. Currently it uses CocoaLumberjack. But I also want the logs to be sent to Crashlytics in case of app crash. So I created a new header file with macroses, which looks basically like this:

```
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
static const DDLogLevel ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelVerbose;
#else
static const DDLogLevel ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelWarning;
#endif

#define BKLogVerbose(frmt,...) DDLogVerbose(frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define BKLogDebug(frmt,...) DDLogVerbose(frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define BKLogInfo(frmt,...) DDLogInfo(frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
                                CLS_LOG(frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define BKLogWarn(frmt,...) DDLogWarn(frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
                                CLS_LOG(frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define BKLogError(frmt,...) DDLogError(frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
                                CLS_LOG(frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Than I'm importing this file where I need extended logging:

```
#import "BKLogging.h"
...
BKLogError(@"%s, error: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
```

But when I try using it I get:

`Implicit declaration of function 'DDLogError' is invalid in C99`

I understand that compiler cannot find DDLogError function declaration, but I don't know how to fix it (I guess I need to import Crashlytics and CocoaLumberjack to every single file where BKLogging is used, but I'm wondering for better solution).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850042/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-is-invalid-in-c99

Comment: Use .pch fie for it (precompile header file) and import Crashlytics and CocoaLumberjack