# LinkedList Objective C - Implicit declaration of function invalid in c99

Tags: objective-c, recursion, linked-list

referencing this post - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850042/xcode-warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-is-invalid-in-c99)

I have my function declared in my header file, however the error -"Implicit declaration of function invalid in c99" still shows.  I am not sure however if that is ultimately what is causing my final error which is "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

I tried changing the architecture in build settings to 386, without luck.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling an Objective-C method looks different than calling a C function. In this instance, you've written a method `-printKthToLast:withHead:`, and you'll need to call it on an object like so:

```
int index = [self printKthToLast:k withHead:head.next] + 1;
```

Note the use of square brackets around the entire method call; the *receiver*, in this case `self`; the individual argument labels; and the lack of parentheses.

Comment: working like a charm now.  Dumb question. Thank you :)