# How to remove implicit declaration of function "lib" is invalid in c99

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, iphone

How to resolve this error. i am using c++ files

```
#include "typedef.h"
#include "P2PLib.h"
```

[image]

I have Checked this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15850385/4970453) but not working

Comment: you use C++ files, but you tag your question as everything but C++. Can you edit the tags? and the error means that you're missing some includes. Maybe the C++ headers miss the `extern "C"` wrappers? Can you show `P2PLib.h` ?

Comment: You don't have the definition of this function in your header. Check your header and/or spelling. Also don't post images of code, post the code as text!

Comment: hi Jean-François Fabre,    My "P2PLib.h" File code is http://paste.ofcode.org/BDSXSP3e7yxg4bJEVP2DQk

Comment: Have you tried to actually compile it? It could be just the IDE false alarm.

Comment: Yes, i have  compiled it. it is showing error @ Eugene Sh.

Comment: Guys Basically i am objective c developer.i am using C++ library for iP Camera

Comment: I am facing same Error.

Comment: It might be something to do with the `P2P_API` macros in the header file, which seem to be defined as appropriate for MS Windows unless the `__linux` macro is defined. Is there a version of the header file that is more appropriate for iOS?

Comment: it could be the compiler is not seeing both parameter to the function as `char *`